# Rails model - NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models:

`app/models/data_science/field_of_studies_job_titles.rb`

```
module DataScience
  class FieldOfStudiesJobTitle < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'ds_campus_transitions_disciplines_current'
    self.primary_keys = :fieldofstudy, :jobrole
  end
end
```

*app/models/field_of_studies_job_title.rb*

```
class FieldOfStudiesJobTitle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job_title
  belongs_to :field_of_study

  validates :job_title_id, uniqueness: { scope: :field_of_study_id }

  def self.import(source)
    source.find_in_batches do |batch|
    batch.each do |item|
      puts "huhu"
    end
  end
end
```

In `rails console`:

```
bundle exec rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.7)
irb(main):001:0> FieldOfStudiesJobTitle.import(::DataScience::FieldOfStudiesJobTitle)
NameError: uninitialized constant DataScience::FieldOfStudiesJobTitle
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Why I get this error message ?

I know it happens when the rails environment is not loaded with the file of the class for which the method was called.

But why it happens in this particular case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filename has a `s` at the end `field_of_studies_job_titles`.

Comment: Such a rookie mistake, thanks! Overlooked it. mv app/models/data_science/field_of_studies_job_title{s,}.rb :)